# prevent php $_REQUEST converting json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, request

Is anyone aware of a way to keep PHP $_REQUEST from converting JSON automatically?  I'm sending data via POST and want to keep some of it in its original form and just store it as a string.

Ideally I'm wanting some simple way to 'escape' a segment of the string.  It seems like there's probably a simple way to do this, but I haven't seen one.

---

Wow...  Please forgive my lack of precision in phrasing this question, I'd been programming pretty much non-stop for several days and was just tired.  I didn't expect a rush to close my question before I could even explain the misunderstanding.

What I meant was that I'm passing javascript objects into jQuery's $.ajax() method as data and using type:"POST" for the call.  I realized later that $.param() is used internally to serialize the object as a query string for the transfer, and that $_REQUEST[] converts objects passed this way into array structures as it would with any complex form data.

---

**client code**

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "some.php", data: {"obj":{"key":"val"},"str":"text"} })
```

Comment: JSON is not converted automatically by PHP.

Comment: It doesn't convert JSON automatically. What makes you think it does?

Comment: Are we talking about magic_quotes perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean by convert? What is it that you're expecting to see in your request, and what are you actually seeing?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. If we can get this thread back open, could you show some client data and code, and maybe a dump of what you're getting in PHP? As I understand your question thus far, PHP does not do what you're saying it does. Seeing the info I requested would help me understand. Thanks!

Comment: It seems you're confused. Yes, if you serialize the object into key:value pairs, you'll get a regular PHP array at the server-side. However, you can use `{post: JSON.stringify(js_object)}` and have entire object being sent as a string, or you can use the above method to manipulate the parts you wish to send as a string.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with *JSON the data format*? Doesn't look like it...?!

Comment: $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: {"obj":{"key":"val"},"str":"text"}
})

Comment: @NB: I may have been confused, but closing the question certainly doesn't help me become not confused. And someone else similarly confused would not be corrected either.  Thanks for the method in your reply though, It's actually what I ended up doing once I got some sleep and looked at the issue again. I was actually going to post the solution but was prevented from doing so by the fact that the question's been closed.

Comment: @jtrick: That's not JSON, nor does it have anything to do with JSON.  That's a JavaScript object.  JSON is a *string representation* of data that just happens to share JavaScript syntax.  In your `$.ajax`, the object is converted to a query string and then `POST`ed to PHP.  PHP takes that query string and converts it to a `$_POST` array.  That's how `$_POST` (and `$_REQUEST`) works.

Comment: @Rocket: Ok, fair enough; in this case it is not, but in my actual case there is a combination of both.

Comment: @jtrick: Can you show us your *actual* case?  Because in this case, it sounds like everything is working the way it should be.  If you really are sending a JSON string, and not a JavaScript object, then it should stay as a string.  PHP does not parse strings for you.  You're probably confusing JSON strings and JavaScript objects.

Comment: @Rocket: Actually I'd also been under the impression that $.ajax() was converting the objects into JSON when it sent the data. I learned soon after that $.param() doesn't actually work that way, but that doesn't mean that my question was so ridiculous that it  had no merit.

Comment: @Rocket: I'll post more information.  I was just fried when I asked the question and hoped that someone might help out.

Comment: @jtrick: Nope, `$.param` converts it to a query string, just like an actual HTML `<form>` would.

Comment: @jtrick:  P.S. I had nothing to do with closing the question.  It may have been because you didn't explain yourself all that much.  You said PHP was converting JSON, and nobody had any idea what you were talking about.  Again, I helped re-open it, I didn't close it.

Comment: @Rocket: No, you're right; I didn't provide much of an explanation at all.  Exhaustion was what prompted me to post the question in the first place, and I left out some key details.  I also did have a misconception about how $.ajax() converted/sent the data, and the phrasing was not ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you perform a jQuery AJAX request, the key/value pairs within data are sent as POST parameters NOT as JSON. If you wish to post the data as JSON, then what you need to do is something similar to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/gist/754454/c6401b8cc461f84799503484a0c780a7622b164d/jQuery.stringify.js"><!-- JSON library --></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = JSON.stringify({"obj":{"key":"val"},"str":"text"}});
  $.ajax({'type':"POST", 'url':"some.php", 'data':{'data':data});
</script>
```

Notice that we are taking what you normally passed as "data" argument but instead, we're creating a post parameter called "data" with a value as a stringified version of the data structure. Also known as JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'd actually discovered this after I'd posted the question but the question was closed before I could correct it.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, I was wanting to be able to do something like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "some.php", 
    data: {
        "obj": {
            "key": "val",
            "keepStr": JSON.stringify({
                "innerObj" {
                    "item1": "val",
                    "item2": "val2"
                }
            })
        },
        "str": "text"
    } 
});
```

and store "innerObj" directly to the db as a JSON string.  As mentioned, I was under the (mistaken) impression that $.ajax() converts the data to JSON for transmission.  As clarified by the other answer, this is not the case, and instead $.param() is used internally for the conversion.

Thanks for the responses, and for re-opening the question.

Comment: For what it's worth, even if some other method were being used to convert the structure to JSON and then back, stringify'ing the nested object as in the above example would still achieve the same result.